# How to make first flag prefilled from dropdown list using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have 2 flags in dropdown, i want first flag in dropdown to be prefilled. Please Help. The Flag with English name must be prefilled and if i change flag, after refresh it must remain with the recently updated flag.

I am here by sharing code:

HTML:

```
<li id="globeList">
   <md-select ng-model="selectedLanguage" aria-label="selectedLanguage2" ng-change="changeLanguage(selectedLanguage)">
       <md-option ng-value="{{item}}" ng-repeat="(index,item) in lans" ng-selected="item.name == langStatus">
           <img src="{{item.image}}" alt="{{item.name}}" title="{{item.name}}">
       </md-option>
   </md-select>
</li>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.langStatus = sessionStorage.getItem("languageName");
      if ($scope.langStatus) {
        userApi.getLangName($scope.langStatus)
               .then(function(success) {
                  $rootScope.languageName = success.data[0];
               }, function(error) {
                  console.log(error);
               })
      } else {
        var lang_name = 'English';
        userApi.getLangName(lang_name)
               .then(function(success) {
                  $rootScope.languageName = success.data[0];
                  sessionStorage.setItem("languageName", lang_name);
               }, function(error) {
                  console.log(error);
               })
      }
$scope.toggleImg = function(art_id, id) {
      var bigImage = angular.element("#" + art_id).attr('src');
      var smallImage = angular.element("#" + id).attr('src');
      angular.element("#" + art_id).attr('src', smallImage);
      angular.element("#" + id).attr('src', bigImage);
    }
    $scope.changeLanguage = function(selectedLanguage) {
      userApi.getLangName(selectedLanguage.name)
             .then(function(success) {
                $rootScope.languageName = success.data[0];
                sessionStorage.setItem("languageName", selectedLanguage.name);
             }, function(error) {
                console.log(error);
             })
    }
```

Comment: did you try with ng-init="selectedLanguage = lans[0]"

Comment: ya i tried, but not working

Comment: Try this as well  ng-init="selectedLanguage= selectedLanguage|| lans[0].value"

Comment: Sorry, not working

Answer (score 0):

Try using below one

```
 <md-select ng-model="selectedLanguage" ng-init="selectedLanguage =  lans[0]" aria-label="selectedLanguage2" ng-
 change="changeLanguage(selectedLanguage)">
   <md-option ng-value="{{item}}" ng-repeat="(index,item) in lans" ng-
  selected="item.name == langStatus">
       <img src="{{item.image}}" alt="{{item.name}}" title="{{item.name}}">
   </md-option>
 </md-select>
```

try to intialize first option in ng-init then it should work for your case

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not loading default Language

```
setDefaultEnglish(); 
function setDefaultEnglish() { 
var test = sessionStorage.getItem("languageName"); 
if(!test){
var lang_name = 'English'; 
sessionStorage.setItem("languageName", lang_name); 
}
};
```